# pfsense: port forwarding rule allow open port but looks close

Tags: ssh, port, pfsense, forwarding

I'm trying to forward the port 2222 to a ssh server running in port 2222, inside the network works fine, so I guess is something in pfsense. I try to do the same in a testing environment and works fine too, I'm checking the port outsite and using nmap I take this:

PORT     STATE    SERVICE      VERSION

2222/tcp filtered EtherNetIP-1

The rules I have in the firewall are those:

IPv4 TCP * * 172.0.0.1 2222 *
IPv4 TCP * * 172.0.0.1 22 *

the point is, the port 22 is redirect too, I want the same for port 2222, but I don't understand why 22 works and why 2222 doesn't, I tried to see the logs but I don't see nothing blocking, some hint please? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after talk with my server provider and check his network everything is running fine, they was using a firewall in front my server, thanks everyone for help me!